# WP Как создать кнопку поделиться постом, для Instagram?

Tags: wordpress, instagram

Есть ли простой, способ создания ссылки поделиться, для `Instagram` ? Без установки сторонних плагинов. *Не могу найти публичного API данной социальной сети.
Пробовал так

```
$title = get_post()->post_title;
$url = get_permalink(); // ссылка на страницу
$summary = get_sub_field('shortdescription'); ;
$image_url = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id());

<li>
<a target="_blank" href="instagram://library?AssetPath=<?php  echo $image_url; ?>&InstagramCaption=<?php echo $summary; ?>" >
 <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/markup-template/markup/img/ico-social-insta.svg" alt="instagram icon">
</a>
</li>
```

Но для `Instagram` Не работает, хотя для `Twitter` все хорошо отрабатывает

```
<li>
  <a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text='<?php echo $title; ?>'&url='<?php echo $url; ?>'" title="Sharing post in Twitter"
 onclick="window.open(this.href, this.title, 'toolbar=0, status=0, width=548, height=325'); return false">
  <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/markup-template/markup/img/ico-social-tw.svg" alt="twitter icon">
 </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Потому что это разные соц. сети) Так-то я не уверен что я вообще видел где либо кнопку шеринга в инстаграм, даже с использованием сторонних сервисов. Вы часто там видели какие-то расшаренные записи где-то?

Comment: нет, этим функционалом не пользуюсь. Как и этой соц. сетью. Она вроде как про картинки, но может кто-то имеет опыт использования. Очень прого материала про встраивание из Instagram в WP `embedding an Instagram post` но вот как шарить в инсте, посты по изображению записи... вопрос.

Comment: Штука в том, что их там не особо есть куда шерить, Вы не можете зашерить его в ленту, например, по идее можно только отправить что-то в качестве личного сообщения или добавить в сторис, но не уверен. Ну и на десктопе скорее всего это не то чтобы будет работать, хоть у инсты и есть веб платформа.